# How to make a simulated sync AJAX call in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, race-condition

I have this script in my app.js:

```
app.run(['$http', '$location', 'myAppConfig', function ($http, $location, myAppConfig) {

    if (myAppConfig.webAPIPath.main == '') {

        var getconfigDone = false;

        $http.get('fileHandler.ashx?action=getconfig')
        .then(function (result) {
            if (JSON.parse(result.data.Data).APIURL !== undefined && JSON.parse(result.data.Data).APIURL != '') {
                var apiURL = JSON.parse(result.data.Data).APIURL;

                if (apiURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 == apiURL.length) {
                    apiURL = apiURL.substring(0, apiURL.lastIndexOf('/'))
                }

                myAppConfig.webAPIPath.main = apiURL + "/";

                myAppConfig.webAPIPath.account = myAppConfig.webAPIPath.main + '/api/OnlineApplicationPortal/v1/Account/';

                myAppConfig.webAPIPath.dashboard = myAppConfig.webAPIPath.main + '/OnlineApplicationPortal/v1/Dashboard/';
            }
            else {
                $location.path('Action/Welcome/apiUrlError');
            }
            //debugger
            getconfigDone = true;

        }, function (response) { debugger }

        );

    }



}]);
```

Also I have got this factory object which uses the `myAppConfig` in app.js:

```
(function () {

    angular
        .module('app.data')
        .factory('accountDS', ['$http', '$routeParams', 'myAppConfig', function ($http, $routeParams, myAppConfig) {
            var pathPrefix = myAppConfig.webAPIPath.account;

            var createAccount = function (account, email) {

                var OnlineApplicationPortalModel = {
                    Name: account.firstName,
                    Surname: account.lastName,
                    Email: email,
                    Password: account.password
                };

                return $http.post(pathPrefix + 'CreateAccount', OnlineApplicationPortalModel)
                    .then(function (response) {

                        return response;
                    });
            };

            var confirmEmail = function () {
                var data = {
                    guid: $routeParams.guid
                };

                return $http.post(pathPrefix + 'ConfirmEmail', data)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response;
                    });
            }

            return {
                createAccount: createAccount,
                confirmEmail: confirmEmail
            };

}]);

})();
```

The service object needs to use `myAppConfig.webAPIPath.account` which is resolved in the function in app.js run function. Now the problem is sometimes the browser reaches the service code sooner than than the AJAX call is returned, a race condition. I know that it is not possible in AngularJS to make a sync AJAX call. So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you, you want to myAppConfig.webAPIPath.account resolve this value to use it later in your code, but ajax call which provides you value for this variable is not always called before assignment. I think you could use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q to solve your problem. Your code in myAppConfig should be inside function, so you can call it inside your factory and return deferred object, which then when your .account variable is set should call code from accountDS factory.

Comment: you got me right mate. I am all new to this space. can you please elaborate this a bit for me by using some code?